# How to use the existing certificates in Kubernetes cluster

Tags: ssl, kubernetes

I have certain questions regarding importing the existing certificates.

1. How are certificates used internally in Kubernetes (e.g. between api server and workers, master controller, etc.)?
   Is there a CA in Kubernetes?  (how) does it generate certificates for internal use?
2. What certificates are required at each layer?

Comment: Here is the official kubernetes page on TLS certificate...https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tls/managing-tls-in-a-cluster/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Certificates in Kubernetes are primarily used to secure communication from and to the API server. Taken from the [official Kubernetes documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tls/managing-tls-in-a-cluster/):

> Every Kubernetes cluster has a cluster root Certificate Authority
>   (CA). The CA is generally used by cluster components to validate the
>   API server’s certificate, by the API server to validate kubelet client
>   certificates, etc. To support this, the CA certificate bundle is
>   distributed to every node in the cluster and is distributed as a
>   secret attached to default service accounts. Optionally, your
>   workloads can use this CA to establish trust. Your application can
>   request a certificate signing using the certificates.k8s.io API using
>   a protocol that is similar to the ACME draft.

When creating a cluster with [kubeadm](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/independent/create-cluster-kubeadm/), the tool at first creates a CA in `/etc/kubernetes/pki` and signs all following certificates with its private key. The ca is later distributed on all nodes for verification and also found base64 encoded in `/etc/kubernetes/admin.conf` for verification of the api server via `kubectl`.

It is possible to use your own CA for cluster creation by placing it and your private key as `ca.crt` and `ca.key` in `/etc/kubernetes/pki` before invoking `kubeadm init` or any folder later specified with `--cert-dir`.

There are many other ways to install Kubernetes but they all essentially create a CA before any actual Kubernetes code runs or require one to exist beforehand.

Comment: Tesor : what is the statefull stateless and daemon containers in kubernetes ? how kubernetes distinguishes between them.